# Ejecutar function PHP que consulta una Query de MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

Buen día a todos, estoy usando `functions` de `PHP` para ejecutar consultas de `MySQL`, Mi problema es:

- Que tengo la consulta pero no se como procesarla dentro de una `function` PHP.

El código:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);


function persona (){
       $cx = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM personas");
       while ($personas = mysqli_fetch_array($cx)): ?>
          <tr>
              <td><?php echo $personas['nombre']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $personas['apepat']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $personas['nro_doc']; ?></td>
         </tr>  
<?php     endwhile; 
     } 
?>



<table>
    <tr>
        <td>nombre</td>
        <td>Apellidos</td>
        <td>DNI</td>
    </tr>
   <?php  persona(); ?>

 </table>
```

**Como debería ser la sintaxis de la `function` y su llamado?**

Answer (score 2):

Para mostrarlo podes armas un string y luego mostrarlo por pantalla, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
function persona (){
     $respuesta = "";
     $cx = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM personas");

     while ($personas = mysqli_fetch_array($cx)){

         $respuesta = $respuesta."<tr><td>".$personas['nombre']."</td><td>".$personas['nombre']."</td><td>".$personas['nombre']."</td></tr>";

     }

     echo $respuesta;
}
```

Comment: estaba probando pero para que funcione la FUNCTION tengo que poner dentro de ella la conexion.